# 'chrome' could not be found and loaded in phpStorm acceptance test

Tags: laravel, selenium, acceptance-testing

I am new to unit testing,
I am new to acceptance testing. I am using laravel 5.5.
The below is my `acceptance.suite.dist.yml`

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
        url: 'http://amazon-ce.localhost.tom/'
        browser: chrome
    - Db
    - Filesystem
config:
  PhpBrowser:
   url: 'http://amazon-ce.localhost.tom/'
WebDriver:
   url: 'http://amazon-ce.localhost.tom/'
   browser: chrome
Db:
  dsn: 'mysql:dbname=myDb;host=127.0.0.1'
  user: 'root'
  password: ''
```

when I run the test, 
it throwing 

`Module WebDriver url: 'http://amazon-ce.localhost.tom/' 
browser: 'chrome' could not be found and loaded`

can anyone help on this.?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work. Remove url and browser detail of **webdriver** in **modules**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
    - Db
    - Filesystem
config:
  PhpBrowser:
   url: 'http://amazon-ce.localhost.tom/'
WebDriver:
   url: 'http://amazon-ce.localhost.tom/'
   browser: chrome
Db:
  dsn: 'mysql:dbname=myDb;host=127.0.0.1'
  user: 'root'
  password: ''
```